# ExpressJS - Not able to create Basic App

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I installed the `express` - using `npm -g express`, And the express is installed globally. which is available on my system in the path of `C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Later I try to create a Basic App, using `express` in the command of `express myApp` ( after I mapped a `sampleFolder`, But the `express` is not providing any basic app settings.

Instead, it throws the error as :

```
D:\Tutorials\Angular\Projects - Angular\NG-SERVER>express myApp
'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the thing which i do incorrect here? any one help me to create `express` basic app please?

I am using `Windows7` here.

Thanks In advance!

Comment: Did you open the cmd using run as administrator? If not, can you try that and tell us if it's still the same?

Comment: Yes I used the admin-rights

Comment: `npm install -g express-generator`.

Answer (score 0):

I run this command to fix my issue:

```
npm install -g express-generator@3
```

thanks to all,